# Location model as polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations, rails-geocoder

I hope I'm forming this question correctly. But I'm trying to create a location model that has a geocoded address and that address is able to be located on a map using `gmap` for  rails.

**My issue is associating my Location model with other application models. Currently I'm attempting to have a location field within my post form.**

My application is as followed using the geocoder and gmaps for rails gems.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :post
geocoded_by :address
acts_as_gmappable

after_validation :geocode 

validates :address, presence: true
validates :latitude, presence: true
validates :longitude, presence: true

def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{address}"
end
validates :locatable, presence: true

end
```

**Post model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :locatable , :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations,:reject_if =>:all_blank ,allow_destroy: true
end
```

Controllers

**Post Controller**

```
def new
  @post= current_user.posts.build
end
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  @post = Location.new
  if @post.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
    flash[:error] = !"
  end
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(locations_attributes[:address,:latitude,:longitude, :locatable_id, :locatable_type, :gmaps])
end
```

**Locations Controller**

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @location = Location.new
end

def create 
  @location = Location.new(params[:location])
end

def destroy
  @location.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to locations_url, notice: 'Location was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private

def location_params
  params.require(:location).permit(:address, :latitude, :longitude, :locatable_id, :locatable_type, :gmaps)
end
end
```

My code might be snippet out but my overall issue is happening within the controller I have everything going right. The location field within my post form is a nested form of the model location, the address field is geocoded and has a location search for the address input. My problem arises when submitting the post, I've tried several methods but I cannot get the location to save to post model. Any help would be amazingly helpful.

Comment: And your schema? Do you have a `post_id` for your Location model?

Comment: I think in your `Location model` shouldn't have `belongs_to :post` this should be removed as long as you are using `polymorphic relationship` to connect `Post` to `Location`

Comment: It is very helpful if you could post your errors. You look to have a number of problems with your code and the error info would help a lot.